# Tmux session disconnect does not preserve session content when reconnecting

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, tmux, sftp

I need to copy a 200gb+ file to multiple servers from one server. I have a sftp transfer running in multiple tmux sessions from the one server.

When I press ctrl+b, d to exit the tmux instance and rejoin with tmux -L , it opens the session to a new console session and does not preserve the progress report of the running sftp.

Is there a way to prevent this behavior? I am using Tmux 2.7.

Commands:

```
tmux new-session -s Upload1

tmux -L Upload1

sftp user@ip

cd /path/to/upload/location    

put file

ctrl+b,d

tmux -L Upload1
```

The sftp process still runs in the background, as I can see the file size increasing every minute.

Comment: (1) How do you start the tmux sessions? and `sftp` within? (2) Do you really need multiple tmux sessions? One tmux session with one window with multiple panes may be enough. (3) When detached from tmux, does `ps aux` show the running tmux server and the `sftp` processes? (4) `tmux -L` allows you to work with a non-default tmux *server*.  How exactly do you use it? Do you even use `tmux -L` to start the sessions is question in the first place? Please [edit] and post exact commands.

Comment: This is a mess. `tmux new-session -s Upload1` creates a new session named `Upload1` within a default tmux server (starting it, if necessary). Any `tmux -L Upload1` creates a new session within a non-default tmux server (starting it, if necessary). To (re)attach to a session you use `tmux attach-session` with `-t` and/or `-L` (if you want to work with a non-default server). Now you may need `-L` to find your old sessions; they are probably within the non-default server identified with `-L Upload1` (which has nothing to do with `-s Upload1` you used before).